# Pythonic-way to append path to several files in the project

Tags: python

I am working on a python project consisting several folders and .py files.
For all files, I have to use `sys.path.append` to introduce my the project directory before importing files from other folders. 
This makes it troublesome if I want to run the code on another PC.
I'd like to want to know if there is a better way so that I don't need to update `sys.path.append` in files when running on another PC?

Comment: Use `sys.path.append` with a relative path, not with an absolute path. Then you're "good to go" regardless of where you run your project from.

Comment: create an environment variable with `project-path` and use that in sys.path.append. configure the `project path`, whenever moved the project code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.path.append` with a relative path, not with an absolute path.

Here is how I do it in one of my projects:

Create file `Config.py`:

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

And import this file in each one of the other files in your project.

Note that `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` is just an example.

Comment: Keep in mind that `__file__` doesn't get along very well with `py2exe` (if you intend to use it at some point).